# unable to launch service catalog product vis lambda function because No launch paths found for resource: prod-hyaxfulvfdtm2

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-service-catalog

The following if my lambda code where if i run locally (without lambda) it works, but when I throw it in lambda it throws `"errorMessage": "No launch paths found for resource: prod-hyaxfulvfdtm2"` while trying to create a provisioned product in AWS service catalog:

```
// import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import { ServiceCatalogClient, ProvisionProductCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-service-catalog';

const client = new ServiceCatalogClient({region: 'us-west-2'});

export const Handler = async (event: any = {
}): Promise<any> => {

try {
    const cmd = new ProvisionProductCommand({
        ProvisionedProductName: event.ProvisionedProductName,
        ProductId: event.ProductId,
        ProvisioningArtifactId: event.ProvisioningArtifactId,
        ProvisioningParameters: [
            {
                Key: 'AccountEmail',
                Value: event.AccountEmail
            },{
                Key: 'AccountName',
                Value: event.AccountName
            },{
                Key: 'ManagedOrganizationalUnit',
                Value: event.ManagedOrganizationalUnit
            },{
                Key: 'SSOUserEmail',
                Value: event.SSOUserEmail
            },{
                Key: 'SSOUserFirstName',
                Value: event.SSOUserFirstName
            },{
                Key: 'SSOUserLastName',
                Value: event.SSOUserLastName
            }
        ],
    });

{

}

    const result = await client.send(cmd);

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(result)
    }
} catch (error) {
    throw(error)
}

}

//(async () => {
//    const result = await Handler()
//    console.log("RESULT: ", result)
//})()
```

If I uncomment that bottom async function & run locally with `node` then it will create the provisioned product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have resolved this issue by adding the role that is already attached to my lambda function as an authorized role in my service catalog portfolio.